# How do I separate JQuery Functions when they only have one start button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css-animations, jquery-animate

So I have a single start button but I want to trigger a sequence of JQuery functions one after another, not all at the same time. This code starts with request1 as red and request2 as white. Then they switch colors and request2 takes the text from request1.

```
$(function() {
        $("input").click(function(){

            document.getElementById('request1').style.cssText = 'background-color: white';

            document.getElementById('request2').style.cssText = 'background-color: red';
        
            document.getElementById("request2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("request1").innerHTML;
        
            document.getElementById("request1").innerHTML = "";
            
        });
    });
```

Since I am dealing with the same elements, I want to change the colors and text again but only after the above code has been executed. Now I want system to take the text from request2 and change colors, but only after request2 got the text from request1.

```
document.getElementById("system").innerHTML = document.getElementById("request2").innerHTML;
        
        document.getElementById('request2').style.cssText = 'background-color: white';

        document.getElementById('system').style.cssText = 'background-color: red';
```

I know I would have to have something to separate the functions and have tried creating a variable called step1 since I am going over two different divs (request1 is its own div and request 2 is its own) and using that to animate under the button trigger function but that didn't work:

```
var step1 = $("step1);
$(function() {
        $("input").click(function(){
            $("step1").animate({

            document.getElementById('request1').style.cssText = 'background-color: white';

            document.getElementById('request2').style.cssText = 'background-color: red';
        
            document.getElementById("request2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("request1").innerHTML;
        
            document.getElementById("request1").innerHTML = "";
           });
        });
    });
```

I am trying to get it to flow like an animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jQuery's in-built animate function and its callback, not the most elegant answer but it should give an idea.

```
$(function () {
  $("input").click(function () {
    // first event
    console.log("Event 1:", new Date());
    $("#request1").animate(
      {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      },
      1000,
      function () {
        // second event
        console.log("Event 2:", new Date());
        $("#request2").animate(
          {
            backgroundColor: "red"
          },
          5000,
          function () {
            // third event
            console.log("Event 3:", new Date());
            $("#request2").html($("#request1").html());

            setTimeout(function () {
              // fourth event
              console.log("Event 4:", new Date());
              $("#request1").html("");
            }, 3000);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Instead of modifying the style with javascript you can make use of the animate style property, which is the first parameter of `.animate()`
You can find out more about `.animate()`

here: https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete

Note: you will need to also add jquery-ui to the `<head>` of the page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay so separating each with its own function and duration . This makes sense and ill look more into the animation function. Thank you!

Comment: It still doesn't do each step one at a time though even with changing the duration and separating the functions. The animate property usually takes in a div, but I am working across two divs

Comment: I have updated my answer with logs and time gaps for testing.

Comment: This didn't work for me, the program doesn't work at all. I tried to implement it into what I already have but that didn't work either